# Serialise List<Dictionary<String,Object>>

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have one List of Dictionary, I want to serialize in Json in c#

```
 protected List<Dictionary<String, Object>> Details;
```

In another handler I want to deserialize this list of dictionary, some proposal?

Comment: Yes. Write some code. Show your effort. And come back when you have more specific problems than *I need code, give me code*.

Comment: var jsonObj = new JsonObject();
             foreach (var item in Details)
             {
             jsonObj.Add(item.Keys,item.Values);
             } How get Current Key in foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily using [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json). Here's an example:

```
    List<Dictionary<String, Object>> Details = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
    {
        new Dictionary<string,object>
        {
            {"abc" , "def"},
            {"123", 234}
        },
        new Dictionary<string,object>
        {
            {"abc1" , "def1"},
            {"1231", 2341}
        }
    };

        // serializing to: [{"abc":"def","123":234},{"abc1":"def1","1231":2341}]
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Details);

        // de-serializing to a new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>.
        List<Dictionary<String, Object>> newDic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<String, Object>>>(json);
```

Comment: How deserialize this object?