# Get Value from JSON String generated from C# WebService

Tags: java, c#, android, json

**This is my C# webservice which generates a JSON String. The below code block is what im using for that.**

```
List<Dictionary<String, Object>> lstdict = new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();

...
...
... 
Logic for connecting db and getting records in msqldat (data reader) 
goes here.
...
...

while (msqldat.Read())
{
     var detls = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     for (int i = 0; i < msqldat.FieldCount; i++)
         {
             detls.Add(msqldat.GetName(i), msqldat.IsDBNull(i) ? null : 
             msqldat.GetValue(i));
             lstdict.Add(detls);
        }
}
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String mret = jss.Serialize(lstdict);
```

**The above webservice is called in a java code from android studio and it returns the below String.**

```
{"GetDataResult":"[
{\"uname\":\"hkIUZIikXVTC5aNaSva8IQ==\",
\"passwd\":\"hkIUZIikXVTC5aNaSva8IQ==\",
\"validupto\":\"\\\/Date(1545330600000)\\\/\",
\"dept\":\"juubHSHgLr\/3JWnrZCh5LeeW5Q7lioWOZ1\/Tg+YRy\/o=\",
\"rid\":1},
{\"uname\":\"hkIUZIikXVTC5aNaSva8IQ==\",
\"passwd\":\"hkIUZIikXVTC5aNaSva8IQ==\",
\"validupto\":\"\\\/Date(1545330600000)\\\/\",
\"dept\":\"juubHSHgLr\/3JWnrZCh5LeeW5Q7lioWOZ1\/Tg+YRy\/o=\",
\"rid\":2}]"}
```

I am trying to get the values in android application by using this Java code :

```
JSONObject uiobj = new JSONObject(mret);
JSONArray arrUserinfo = uiobj.getJSONArray("GetDataResult");
arrUserinfo.getJSONObject(0).getString("uname"))
```

The code fails at the second line.  I'm new to JSON.  Not sure if the JSON generated from c# code is not right or java code for parsing is not right.  Please advise further.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code fails at the second line? Post stacktrace?

Comment: Your json data is not well formatted. Thats why it fails. I think the escape characters are doing this. Go to https://jsonformatter.org/ and paste your json data there to see weather it is formatted right or not

Comment: It seems like portions of your JSON have been double-serialized, along the lines of [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179) -- even though you're using `JavaScriptSerializer` not `Json.NET`.  Can you show how you return your JSON from your webservice?

Comment: @AswinPAshok Thank you for the response.  I referred jsonformatter.org and found that JSON is not in valid format.  Thank you.

Comment: @dbc Thank you for your response.  This is how Iam returning from WebService.

Comment: @dbc Thank you for your response.  I have shown the code which I use in the webservice.  It is a List<Dictionary<String, Object>> type object im using and filling up the list with entries in the table, finally using JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String mret = jss.Serialize(lstdict);  and returning this string back to the caller.

Comment: Can anyone help me to correct the JSON output from C#

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897894/serialise-listdictionarystring-object)

Comment: @AshwinPAshok lstdict is a collection so i cannot return that.. Thanks.

Comment: did you check this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897894/serialise-listdictionarystring-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above json is serialized you need to parse json and then extract the object from it.

See this json valid..

```
{
    "GetDataResult": [{
            "uname": "hkIUZIikXVTC5aNaSva8IQ==",
            "passwd": "hkIUZIikXVTC5aNaSva8IQ==",
            "validupto": "/Date(1545330600000)/",
            "dept": "juubHSHgLr/3JWnrZCh5LeeW5Q7lioWOZ1/Tg+YRy/o=",
            "rid": 1
        },
        {
            "uname": "hkIUZIikXVTC5aNaSva8IQ==",
            "passwd": "hkIUZIikXVTC5aNaSva8IQ==",
            "validupto": "/Date(1545330600000)/",
            "dept": "juubHSHgLr/3JWnrZCh5LeeW5Q7lioWOZ1/Tg+YRy/o=",
            "rid": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

To parse json in java see below post..

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parse-json-java/

Comment: Thank you so much for help.  I got the mistake in my JSON String.  But it is automatically generated from c# class.   Yet JSONParser returns an unknown symbol.

Comment: Ok. I got the JSONParser working.  I think I need to correct the JSON Output from C# first to the one you have shown here. I will try to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Yes json output is serialized.